# Ver las tablas de un usuario Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy trabajando una base de datos en SQL Developer, cree un usuario llamado Nagato2 y con el cree una conexión llamada prueba2, en la que metí todas mis tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, se me pidió crear un usuario nuevo dentro de esta conexión al que llame Nagato3. Al crear una conexión llamada prueba3 con el usuario Nagato3 y revisar la sección de tablas no me aparecen las tablas que si aparecían en prueba2 (Imagen 2). ¿Cómo hacer para que las tablas aparezcan aquí?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El usuario `ngato3` no tiene permisos sobre las tablas del usuario `ngato2`. Si quires que `ngato3` pueda *ver* las tablas de `ngato2`, debes comenzar por darle permisos, con la instrucción [`grant`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm), por ejemplo:

```
connect ngato2@oracle.home
grant select on miTabla1 to ngato3;
grant all on miTabla2 to ngato3;
grant select, update, delete on miTabla3 to ngato3;
```

El usuario `ngato3`, podrá ver las tablas de `ngato2`, pero aún tendrá que calificarlas para utilizarlas, por ejemplo:

```
select * from ngato2.miTabla1;
```

Si `ngato3` lo desea, para evitar tener que calificar las tablas, puede crear *sinónimos* hacia las tablas de ngato2, con el nombre que desee, aunque lo recomendable es que tengan el mismo nombre.

```
connect ngato3@oracle.home;
create synonym mitabla1 for ngato2.mitabla1;
create synonym OtroNombre for ngato2.mitabla1;
```

de esta forma, `ngato3` puede acceder a las tablas de `ngato2` sin calificarlas:

```
select * from mitabla1;
```

traerá los datos de `ngato2.mitabla2`.

finalmente, `ngato2`, el sysdba o ccualquier otro usuario con privilegios, puede crear un sinónimo público a las tablas (u otros objetos), de manera que nadie tenga que calificarlas:

```
connect sys@oracle.home;
create public synonym mitabla1 for ngato2.mitabla1;
```

Esto hará que cualquier usuario pueda realizar la sentencia sobre `mitabla1` sin necesidad de calificarla.

```
select * from mitabla1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Desde un usuario administrador puedes

```
SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE owner ='BD' ORDER BY table_name;
```